# Using Sublime Text to ensure one sentence per line in LaTeX documents

Tags: regex, latex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

The goal is to adopt the [third way](http://www.xkcd.com/1285/)---a.k.a. using [semantic linefeeds](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/one-sentence-per-line/). This involves typing one sentence per line of a TeX file. This makes it easier to use version control systems when working with TeX files and other, text-heavy files. (A similar recommendation was made in answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133365/configure-git-to-work-with-latex-i-e-use-dots-instead-of-lines-as-reference-po).)

Of course, I could manually insert a line break at the end of every sentence. However, this would lead to bad habits (e.g. typing a sentence per line when writing emails). So I'm looking for an alternative way of implementing this.

One solution, for those of us using Sublime Text, is to use ST's keybindings. Essentially, this would turn the spacebar into a keyboard shortcut for a script that will

- check whether what precedes it is the end of a sentence, and
- if it is, insert a line break.

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
{ "keys": [" "],
        "context":  [
                {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
                {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "(^.+\\.$)|(^.+\\?$)|(^.+\\!$)|(^.+\\.+\\)$)"},
                {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_match", "operand": "(^.*\\\\ex\\.$)|(^.*\\\\[abz]\\.$)"},
                {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_match", "operand": "(^.*[Cc]f\\.$)|(^.*\\b[Pp]+\\.$)|(^.*etc\\.$)|(^.*\\b[A-Z]\\.$)|(^\\w\\.$)|(^.*M[sr]\\.$)|(^.*Mrs\\.$)"}
                ],
        "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": " %\n"}
    }
```

I append this to `Sublime/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` and it seems to do the trick.

The snippet is supposed to look for what precedes the space, and give you a match if you have a string that ends with one of the following:

- a period,
- an exclamation mark,
- a question mark,
- a closing parenthesis preceded by a period.

It will however ignore strings that end with a period if they are preceded by one of the following:

- '\ex', '\a', '\b', '\z' (this is to be able to use the `linguex` package),
- 'cf', 'Cf',
- 'p', 'pp', 'P',
- 'etc'
- 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Dr',
- Single capital letters (for use of initials in a sentence).

I'm curious to see if there are other things I should add to that list ('Ibid', I suppose would be one).

I'm also wondering whether there are any less clunky solutions to this problem.

Comment: Why are you using additional non regex matches?

Comment: I thought it'd be easier to read that way. Also, for those who do not use `linguex`, they could comment out the first of the non regex matches.

Comment: you also need to allow for white spaces after a \. This case may arise if you copy paste stuff `(^.+\\..*?$)`....

Comment: you could auto-correct `.`/`!`/`?` and two spaces into a newline if you're ok with picking up a two-space habit.  http://www.serif.com/appresources/PPX6/Tutorials/en-us/help/autocorrect.htm

Comment: I went through my own LaTeX files and the only case you're missing I could find is `et al.`.

Comment: While this is a good question, it is still some sort of a kitchen sink question: "Please, throw in everything you have. I will figure out." So, an objective and complete answer is almost impossible. See it more as a process, until your exclusion list stabilizes.

Comment: On `Mr. Jack` any regexps will fail. So transforming existing text would require manual work on checking each case :( As for brand new text is it possible to add some non-visual marker at the end of each sentense?

Answer (score 1):

Unless one is using `\frenchspacing` ([1](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Space_between_words_and_sentences), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_spacing#French_and_English_spacing)) there should *never* be a period `.` followed by space if it is not the end of a sentence.
Latex makes a difference between periods at the end of a sentence and periods in sentences.
Space after a sentence will be a larger-than-usual amount of space.

So, if you want to ensure *one sentence per line* you only need to act on periods followed by a space.

Any period that is **not** an end of a sentence should be followed by either:

- `\,` small space
- `\` interword spacing (space after `\`)
- `~`  non-breaking space

<sup>Just for reference: Latex uses `\@` to explicitly mark a period as end of sentence (intersentence spacing).</sup>